# Программа ошибок не выдает,но и не работает

Tags: c++, наследование, visual-studio-code, перегрузка-операторов

Написал программу(учу наследование),программа ошибок не выдает,но и работать тоже отказывается.Можете помочь,обьясните,направьте...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class chelovek
{
protected:
    const char* m_pol;
    std::string m_name;
    int m_vozrast;
public:

    chelovek(const char* pol, std::string name, int vozrast) :
        m_pol(pol), m_name(name), m_vozrast(vozrast) {};

    const char* get_pol()
    {
        return m_pol;
    }

    std::string get_name()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    int get_vozrast()
    {
        return m_vozrast;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::string d1);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, std::string d);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::string d1)
{
    out << d1;
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, std::string d)
{
    in >> d;
    return in;
}

class uchenik : public chelovek
{
private:
    const char* m_klass;
public:

    uchenik(const char* pol, std::string name, int vozrast, const char* klass) :
        m_klass(klass), chelovek(pol, name, vozrast) {};

    const char* get_klass()
    {
        return m_klass;
    }

};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    int vozrast;
    std::cin >> vozrast;
    uchenik vova("мужской", name, vozrast, "11_А");
    std::cout << vova.get_klass() << vova.get_name() << vova.get_pol() << vova.get_vozrast() << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Осталось только выяснить: а что значит не работает?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,она не дает ввести данные,и не выводит,а лишь завершается....

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы за писываете введённую строку во временный объект `d`, который сразу-же уничтожается.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, std::string d)
{
  in >> d;
  return in;
}
```

Нужно аргумент сделать как ссылку :

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, std::string & d)
```

А лучше просто убрать это определение. А то происходит бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Так они вообще не нужны. Наверное ТС должен был перегрузить эти операторы для своих классов, а не для `std::string`, для которого эти операторы уже определены. Ведь строка `in >> d;` вроде как является рекурсивным вызовом этого же оператора.

Comment: да,спасибо за эту заметку,но программа всё равно не работает...

Comment: Спасибо @EOF у вас всё равно будет бесконечно зацикливаться оператор, удалите его.

Comment: @AlexGleb,удалив перегруженный оператор ввода,я лишился возможности вводит данные типа STRING...я не вижу смысла его удаления...

Comment: я удалил функции и дружественность, всё пашет, проверил

Comment: @AlexGlebe,вводится и выводится??? У меня ошибки с отсутствием 2 операторов соответствующим этим операндам...

Comment: Ну скажите тогда версию компилятора, может кто-то знает, что за лажа и скажет.

Comment: @AlexGlebe MVS 2015 Community версия-14.0.23107.178

Comment: @Vovi https://ideone.com/VajWzD Вы же в курсе, что `std::cin >> name;` прочитает только одно слово

Comment: @EOF да...спасибо,за заметку

Comment: "VС++ ToolKit, или как он там у VS называется, поставьте. " советовали в https://qna.habr.com/q/363708 Вы как решили этот вопрос?